# Issues with downloading PDF file from source

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

iv'e created a method to generate a pdf file from a form, it got saved to the correct path using itexsharp, but the problem is i can't download it.

this is my code :

```
private void FillForm(Dictionary<string, string> dic)
{

    var pdfTemplate = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ress/GENE_15_04_2014.pdf"); //_pdfTemplet;

    var newFile = _newFileName + "_" + Guid.NewGuid() + ".pdf";

    _gNewFile = newFile.ToString();

    var pdfReader = new PdfReader(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pdfTemplate));

    var pfileStream = new FileStream(string.Format(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ress/") + "{0}", newFile), FileMode.Create);

    var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, pfileStream);
    var pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

    foreach (var entry in dic)
    {
        pdfFormFields.SetField(entry.Key, entry.Value);
    }
    pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
    pdfStamper.JavaScript = "this.print(true);\r";
    pdfStamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;
    pdfReader.Close();
    pdfStamper.Close();
    UPContract.Update();
    pfileStream.Close();
    pdf.FilePath = string.Format("../Ress/{0}", Path.GetFileName(_gNewFile));

    Response.Clear();
    byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(string.Format(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ress/") + "{0}", _gNewFile));
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "fiche abonnement_" + _gNewFile + ".pdf");
    Response.Buffer = true;
    ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to create the PDF as a file on the server unless you need to archive that file. Do you need to archive that file?

Comment: yes of course for special needs

Comment: you still there @BrunoLowagie !

Comment: Yes, but this isn't an iText or iTextSharp question, this is a C# question: how do I read the bytes of a file and send them to the `Response`? I am a Java developer, not a C# developer, so you'll have to ask someone else. Also: this question has been answered *many, many times before* on StackOverflow, so if you want the answer, you may want to search through some older questions.

Comment: *i can't download it.* - What exactly do you mean? Is there an error message? Or is there only an empty page? Or does the client computer explode?

Comment: @mkl i got no errors the code is clean the page just loading and then stops after that, doesn't download the file i've generated.

Comment: In your `content-disposition` header parameter `filename` value there is a space character. In such a case the value must be quoted, cf. [RFC 6266](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6266).

Comment: Bring up your browser's inspector tools and inspect the response headers that your client is actually receiving, this will tell you if you are getting what you are sending

Comment: @mkl I've removed the space character, nothing changed !

Comment: Have you tried with different browsers? Have you done as proposed by @Chris?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a file you can skip the byte array and `MemoryStream` and just use [`Response.WriteFile(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dyfzssz9(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: i don't have a problem with passing the file , the problem is to download it !